# Full Duplex Shared Folders in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, rsync, shared-directory

I have a guest box that has data I want to sync to the host so that I am able to edit it using an editor on the host. I want any saved changes made on the host to sync back to the guest. I've tried using normal shared folders `config.vm.synced_folder "workspace/", "/my/folder/to/sync/"` but this just deletes the contents of the guest folder!
I've looked at using `rsync` but I'm unsure if this supports editing and syncing both ways

Comment: _but this just deletes the contents of the guest folder_ yes if you want to sync an existing folder, vagrant will replace the content of the folder by the content from your host (as you mount the drive to an existing folder, it replaces the content) - as for bi-directionaly sync, it should work automatically by default using virtual box shared folder, do not use rsync

Comment: @Rob Have you tried to use NFS, it works well and have many option when mounting the file system.

Answer (score 0):

**Rsync** is type performs one-way synchronization fromm host to guest. When you boot the VM, Vagrant copies the contents of the synchronized folder from host to guest. Vagrant does not monitor the folder on the host for any changes. To change this behavior, use the rsync_auto parameter set to true.